# "AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'" when trying to use youtube-dl

Tags: youtube-dl

The error comes in a statement like this

```
WARNING: Automatic signature extraction failed: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/youtube_dl/extractor/youtube.py", line 957, in _decrypt_signature
    video_id, player_url, len(s)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/youtube_dl/extractor/youtube.py", line 331, in _extract_signature_function
    player_type = id_m.group('ext')
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'

WARNING: Warning: Falling back to static signature algorithm
```

Any sort of help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: What version of `youtube-dl` do you have?

Answer (score 1):

That's a python error.

Something went wrong with the version of youtube-dl you're using. I've never used it, so I can't tell you for sure if you improperly used it, or if it just has a bug.

@Richard asked what version you're using - this issue may or may not be resolved in a newer version of the program.

Looking at the [dev's github](http://rg3.github.io/youtube-dl/download.html) there was a release just last friday - he has instructions there on how to install it, I'd give that a shot. [There are a few issues that match "NoneType"](https://github.com/rg3/youtube-dl/issues?q=is%3Aissue++NoneType), maybe one of those matches the exact issue you're seeing?

Answer (score -1):

YouTube changed their player on July 25, 2014. You will need youtube-dl version 20140725 or newer.

You may want to use your package manager, I believe it is apt-get on ubuntu to see it that brings you up-to-date.

Some distributions are a bit behind so you may want to uninstall the package-manager version and install directly from the developers site. As long as you have Python 2.6/2.7 this should work:

```
sudo curl -L -s  https://yt-dl.org/downloads/latest/youtube-dl -o /usr/local/bin/youtube-dl
sudo chmod a+x /usr/local/bin/youtube-dl
```

Comment: Welcome to AU and thanks for your contribution! We encourage our users to [write high quality answers](https://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-answer). While you may have a valid description of the underlying problem, your answer provides no advice how to solve it. Maybe you can describe how to find out the current installed version, or provide a link to instructions on how to update `youtube-dl` with a citation of the crucial part(s).